# Recommendation for sklearn model persistent

Tags: scikit-learn, machine-learning-model

I want to serve a `sklearn` model in server, any suggestions what is best format/method to save `sklearn` models. Currently I am using `pickle.dump` method to save the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html):

> It is possible to save a model in scikit-learn by using Python’s
> built-in persistence model, namely pickle [...] In the specific case
> of scikit-learn, it may be better to use joblib’s replacement of
> pickle (dump & load), which is more efficient on objects that carry
> large numpy arrays internally as is often the case for fitted
> scikit-learn estimators, but can only pickle to the disk and not to a
> string [...]

I usually use [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html) as it is very practical.

```
from joblib import dump, load
dump(clf, 'filename.joblib') 

clf = load('filename.joblib')
```

As of Version 1.0.2. there is an additional remark on "[interoperable formats](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#interoperable-formats)":

> For reproducibility and quality control needs, when different
> architectures and environments should be taken into account, exporting
> the model in Open Neural Network Exchange format or Predictive Model
> Markup Language (PMML) format might be a better approach than using
> pickle alone. These are helpful where you may want to use your model
> for prediction in a different environment from where the model was
> trained [...]

So in case you want to be flexible, you should look into [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/) or [PMML](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-4-1/GeneralStructure.html).

Comment: Is it better to use ONNX or PMML format rather than joblib format?

Comment: In case you have no reason to believe that you will leave the Python/sklearn framework, there is no need for these tools. They are a „general“ framework to share models in different packages. I don‘t use them by now. I use joblib which is clean and easy

Comment: With joblib you can also save scalers and transformers. Also very handy!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `scikit-learn` documentation, specifically [the page on model persistence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)? They mention `pickle` as an option, but also note that using `joblib` may be better because of efficiency on larger numpy arrays.

Comment: Yes I did. I just need an expert opinion on that. I have zero experience so I wanted to explore some other options too. I also heard about ONNX too.